# Multiple replacement in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Is there a way to replace multiple captured groups and replace it with the *value* of the captured groups from a key-value format (delimited by `=`) in `sed`?

Sorry, that question is confusing so here is an example

What I have:

```
aaa="src is $src$ user is $user$!" src="over there" user="jason"
```

What I want in the end:

```
aaa="src is over there user is jason!"
```

I don't want to hardcode the position of the `$var$` because they could change.

Comment: `Sed` is a wrong tool for this task. It lacks of many data and control structures of the most powerful languages.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I still have to do this task programmatically then.

Comment: sed is create for such a kind of task. Not the simpliest but still relatively easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed ':again
s/\$\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)\$\(.*\) \1="\([^"]*\)"/\3\2/g
t again
' YourFile
```

As you see, sed is absolut not interesting doing this kind of task ... even with element on several line it can work with few modification and it doesn not need a quick a dirty 6 complex line of higher powerfull languages.

principe:

1. create a label (for a futur goto)
2. search an occurence of a patterne between $ $ and take his associate content and replace pattern with it and following string but without the pattern content definition
3. if it occur, try once again by restarting at the label reference of the script. If not print and treat next line

Comment: Why does there have to be a line break at `t again`? I tried to do everything in one line and it didn't work.

Comment: depend on sed version i think, some work on GNU sed. Thie reason is due to label convention that must ended the line and ; seemns not working as end of line in this case. maybe a format to use, like space before and/or after. I have to check the oneliner page to see if some label ref work also on posix sed

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick & dirty way to solve it using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It could fail in some ways (spaces, escapes double quotes, ...), but it would get the job done for most simple cases:

```
perl -ne '
    ## Get each key and value.
    @captures = m/(\S+)=("[^"]+")/g;

    ## Extract first two elements as in the original string.
    $output = join q|=|, splice @captures, 0, 2;

    ## Use a hash for a better look-up, and remove double quotes
    ## from values.
    %replacements = @captures;
    %replacements = map { $_ => substr $replacements{$_}, 1, -1 } keys %replacements;

    ## Use a regex to look-up into the hash for the replacements strings.
    $output =~ s/\$([^\$]+)\$/$replacements{$1}/g;

    printf qq|%s\n|, $output;
' infile
```

It yields:

```
aaa="src is over there user is jason!"
```